# HP Proliant DL160 G5 - how to remove ILO License

Tags: hp-proliant, ilo

I bought a HP ProLiant DL160 G5 off eBay some time ago for use as a file server for a LAN party group (specifically I was after something with four 3.5" bays on the front) - but it turned out to be not powerful enough for my needs (iSCSI) so I upgraded.  I now wish to sell it on eBay again but the license on the ILO, I found out, wasn't exactly... legit.  I don't want to get into trouble for what the last guy did, is there any way to clear this license?

Comment: ILO licensing is on-your-honor... People reuse, recycle and steal/pirate the keys all the time. If it's already installed on this server, you may as well use it. Removing the key will probably just cause you or someone else a bit of inconvenience down the road. May I ask how you determined that the key was not "*legit*"?

Comment: Admission from the seller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need to remove the ILO license. Nobody is going to care, and HP isn't interested in auditing the license status of such an old server.

But if you can open an SSH connection to the ILO using username: `Administrator`, just run:

```
delete /map1 license
```

That's all you'll need.

---

***Edit:*** My mistake. This server is a ProLiant DL160 G5, so it doesn't even use a full-featured ILO2, but rather an embedded Lights-Out 100i. This requires a different approach:

[image]

My opinion is that you should leave the key in place. There's little to gain by removing it. The LO100i is so limited that the presence of the key isn't really an addition. I went through the normal options on my LO100i, and can't find a way to remove the key; only options to replace it. I also checked the support manual. No luck.